# Creating switchable Bootstrap 4 theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I understand that the way to theme a site build using Bootstrap is to override default variables to change colours, fonts, sizes etc. I’m doing so in my application to provide the basic theme, with minor variations from the standard Bootstrap look.

There’s now a requirement for users to be able to switch to a dark theme if they'd prefer. This would change colours of most components (e.g. buttons, tabs, navs, cards).

Since the core structure will remain the same (e.g. `.btn` will still have almost exactly the same CSS apart from colours), it seems like it would be overkill to build 2 versions of bootstrap.css from different variables and what I actually need is an override.

So, I believe there are a couple of options but would welcome input from anyone who's had to do this sort of thing before.

1. Create a theme-dark.css file that only overrides colours directly (e.g. `.card-header { background-color: black; color: white; }`) then have this CSS included only if the dark theme is selected.
2. Include all the dark theme colours in the main stylesheet under a single class that I can switch on the `<body>`. E.g. `.theme-dark .card-header { … }`

The trouble I'm having with both approaches is that it’s overriding styles and duplicating a lot of styles. What would be great is if Bootstrap was split into structure and theme Sass files that could either be built into one CSS file (standard use-case) or could be built into something like `bootstrap.css` / `bootstrap-theme-light.css` / `bootstrap-theme-dark.css` in my case so I can switch between the last two.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 supports the configuration you want.  Bootstrap 4 will presumably have similar (SASS/LESS) support once it's out of alpha and actually meant for production use.

Comment: I believe it already does, using Sass variables. However, that just lets me create a whole bootstrap.css for each theme when I really want to just change the 'theme' bit of it (e.g. colours, fonts) rather than structure (e.g. grid, padding, margins) without duplication or overrides (if avoidable).

Comment: You have two options.  (a) You use SASS to customize Bootstrap as a whole, or (b) You use an override that will (unavoidably) result in duplicate code... at least insofar as you'll be setting things like `.btn-default { background: coral; }` to override the default styles.